# why is Immutable Objects safe in Double-Checked Locking?

Tags: java, thread-safety, immutability, double-checked-locking

At the about bottom of http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html, it says:

> > Double-Checked Locking Immutable Objects
> >
> > If Helper is an immutable object, such that all of the fields of Helper are final, then double-checked locking will work without having to use volatile fields. The idea is that a reference to an immutable object (such as a String or an Integer) should behave in much the same way as an int or float; reading and writing references to immutable objects are atomic.

The sample and explanation of mutable one is as follows:

```
// Broken multithreaded version
// "Double-Checked Locking" idiom
class Foo { 
  private Helper helper = null;
  public Helper getHelper() {
    if (helper == null) 
      synchronized(this) {
        if (helper == null) 
          helper = new Helper();
      }    
    return helper;
    }
  // other functions and members...
  }
```

> > The first reason it doesn't work
> >
> > The most obvious reason it doesn't work it that the writes that initialize the Helper object and the write to the helper field can be done or perceived out of order. Thus, a thread which invokes getHelper() could see a non-null reference to a helper object, but see the default values for fields of the helper object, rather than the values set in the constructor.
> >
> > If the compiler inlines the call to the constructor, then the writes that initialize the object and the write to the helper field can be freely reordered if the compiler can prove that the constructor cannot throw an exception or perform synchronization.
> >
> > Even if the compiler does not reorder those writes, on a multiprocessor the processor or the memory system may reorder those writes, as perceived by a thread running on another processor.

My question is: why immutable class does't have the problem? I cannot see any relation of the reorder with whether the class is mutable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code is "broken" for usual objects is that `helper` could be non null but point to an object that has not been *completely initialised* yet as explained in your quote.

However if the Helper class is immutable, meaning that all its fields are final, [the Java Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) guarantees that they are safely published even if the object is made available through a data race (which is the case in your example):

> `final` fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. ***A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads***. This can provide safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by incorrect or malicious code. `final` fields must be used correctly to provide a guarantee of immutability.

Comment: I think your term of "completely initialised" means something different with the one in your link? "An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields."

Comment: No it is the same: after the call to `new Helper()`, the JMM guarantees that final fields have been initialised but does not say anything about regular fields which may or may not have been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable classes did have the problem.  The part that you have quoted is true **after** changes to the Java Memory were made in JSR133.

Specifically the changes that affect immutable objects are related to some changes that were made to the `final` keyword.  Checkout http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight.

The important part is:

> The values for an object's final fields are set in its constructor. Assuming the object is constructed "correctly", once an object is constructed, the values assigned to the final fields in the constructor will be visible to all other threads without synchronization.